# How can I prevent overshadowing during ADL?

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

Suppose I have a class that extends a (STL) container and provides a customary `begin` member function:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename Cont>
struct Bar {
    Cont c;
    auto my_begin() { return begin(c); }
};

int main() {
    Bar<std::vector<int>> b;
    b.my_begin();
}
```

By ADL, I do not have to specify `std::` before the `begin()` call. This is nice, as `std::begin(v)` will always try to call `v.begin()`, a user may want to use a custom container that has no `.begin()` interface, so if he defines his own free-function `begin(v)`, `Bar` will use it.
However, it seems ADL will no longer work if I rename `my_begin` to `begin` as well, as if it was overshadowed. The compiler will just complain that it cannot find a matching call to begin in the class scope:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'auto Bar<Cont>::begin() [with Cont = std::vector<int>]':
prog.cc:11:13:   required from here
prog.cc:6:27: error: use of 'auto Bar<Cont>::begin() [with Cont = std::vector<int>]' before deduction of 'auto'
    6 |     auto begin() { return begin(c); }
      |                           ^~~~~
prog.cc:6:32: error: no matching function for call to 'Bar<std::vector<int> >::begin(std::vector<int>&)'
    6 |     auto begin() { return begin(c); }
      |                           ~~~~~^~~
prog.cc:6:10: note: candidate: 'auto Bar<Cont>::begin() [with Cont = std::vector<int>]'
    6 |     auto begin() { return begin(c); }
      |          ^~~~~
prog.cc:6:10: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Of course, by writing `std::begin`, the code will run again, but this would just manifest the exclusion of ADL. What can I do, apart from renaming the member function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the two step method:

```
    auto begin() { 
        using std::begin;   //1
        return begin(c);    //2
    }
```

`1`: bring `std::begin` into consideration
`2`: If `c` has `begin()` in its namespace, call that, otherwise default to `std::begin()`

You can read more about it [here](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/07/11/the-std-swap-two-step/)

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to write a standalone helper function that specifically uses ADL on `begin`:

```
template <typename C>
decltype(auto) adl_begin(C && c)
{
    using std::begin;
    return begin(std::forward<C>(c));
}
```

And then call `adl_begin` from within your class.

The `using std::begin;` part is there so that the function even works with primitive arrays.